# CSS transitions, why do some of my element transitions take longer than others when they all use the same rule?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

So quick background. I am making a dark mode stylesheet for Bulma where I am just swapping out the SCSS variables and rebuilding all the components. Basically I have something like this:

```
/* entry.scss */

.is-light-mode {
  @import default-variables.scss;
  @import component-1.scss;
  @import component-2.scss;
  @import component-3.scss;
  ...
}

.is-dark-mode {
  @import dark-mode-variables.scss;
  @import component-1.scss;
  @import component-2.scss;
  @import component-3.scss;
  ...
}

* {
  transition:
    color .4s,
    background-color .4s,
    border-color .4s;
}
```

default-variables.scss and dark-mode-varables.scss are just place holders for my initial and derived variables for both light and dark mode.

So the idea is that I have all my light and dark mode in a single css file and then a wildcard CSS rule to set the transitions for every single elements' text color, bg color, and border colors.

It *mostly* works but I found that my `.content {}` text is noticeably slower than everything else.

I made this codepen to show what I am seeing:

https://codepen.io/kjennings83t/pen/wvXJdXx

So first, if you toggle the dark mode with the button at the top and watch the "post date" text under the content you'll see that the color transition is much slower than everything else.

You'll also see that the post content itself is even worse. But if you jump into the CSS and uncomment lines 20-22 the content transition will now work as expected.

So why are these specific transitions slower than everything else?

EDIT - it looks like things work expected in Firefox

Comment: maybe because of `*` selector there is an issue with nested elements being transitioned at the same time.

Comment: Definitively a Chrome bug: https://jsfiddle.net/yuwpv4cn/ I'll report it after I run a quick bisect. What seems to happen is that they do invalidate the child transition from the parent's one and start it again (the child one). So you end up having the full time of the parent one + the full time of the child one.

Comment: So this is actually https://crbug.com/1111817

Answer (score 2):

The content will first inherit the color and then apply the transition so it's like you have 2 transitions running.

Here is a simplified example to better see the issue. On hover the last one will be faster because we have no transition on the `p` element

```css
.box {
  color: red;
}
body:hover .box {
  color: blue;
}

* {
  transition: .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <p>Flannel selfies portland cronut. Leggings meh subway tile godard church-key tumeric fam hoodie vegan. Twee gochujang selvage, echo park hammock marfa synth glossier street art pabst celiac disrupt direct trade. Live-edge hot chicken enamel pin tofu, 3 wolf moon chillwave artisan four loko 8-bit gastropub PBR&B</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
 <p style="transition:0s">Flannel selfies portland cronut. Leggings meh subway tile godard church-key tumeric fam hoodie vegan. Twee gochujang selvage, echo park hammock marfa synth glossier street art pabst celiac disrupt direct trade. Live-edge hot chicken enamel pin tofu, 3 wolf moon chillwave artisan four loko 8-bit gastropub PBR&B </p>
</div>
```

To fix your issue, try to reduce the transition as much as possible to avoid the cascading effect or try to avoid having inherited properties with transition.

Comment: Even if there were two transitions, why would their duration add up?

Comment: BTW - this works as expected in firefox. I think as Kaiido mentioned it might be a chrome bug

Comment: Oh wow, this would never have crossed my mind! Thanks, works perfectly!